# Firebase gives fatal error when importing getDatabase()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications

I'm new to JS, and have tried to figure out the error by digigng into it and reasearched other quesitons about Firebase on StackOverflow, without finding any solution.

I'm trying to implement a realtime DB in JS. But when I'm using getDatabase(), I get fatal error, and I can't see to find out the solution for it, or why it happens.

This is the error:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database URL must point to the root of a Firebase Database (not including a child path).
> Uncaught Error Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database URL must point to the root of a Firebase Database (not including a child path).

This is the code I'm using:

```
import {initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js"
import {getDatabase, ref, push} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js"

const appSettings = {
    databaseURL: "MY URL"
}

const app = initializeApp(appSettings)
const database = getDatabase(app)
const shoppingListInDB = ref(database, "shoppingList")
 
const inputFieldEl = document.getElementById("input-field")
const addButtonEl = document.getElementById("add-button")

addButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let inputValue = inputFieldEl.value

    push(shoppingListInDB, inputValue)
    console.log("It works")

    console.log(`${inputValue} added to database`)
})
```

It works fine, until I implement getDatabase(app).

Comment: What value do you use for `"MY URL"`? Hiding that from us is unfortunately not an option here, as the error message comes from the value you use. In general, you should copy/paste this value from the configuration snippet in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like you have settings like this:

```
const appSettings = {
    databaseURL: "https://<your-project>.<domain>/PATH/TO/DATA"
}
```

That is not correct however, and should be just the base URL without the path to the data:

```
const appSettings = {
    databaseURL: "https://<your-project>.<domain>/"
}
```

So if your project is called `stackoverflow` and your database is in the US, that'd be:

```
const appSettings = {
    databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/"
}
```

If your database is in another region, the last two parts of that URL would be different. But the important thing is that you only include the base URL, and no path to the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)
This is how I wrote my URL:

```const appSettings = {
    databaseURL: "https://<my-project>.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/ "
}```

That is directly copied from my realtime-db